# Differentiating under integral sign, capital accumulation

Tags: macroeconomics, mathematical-economics

I am reading a paper, the author takes the derivative of the following equation with respect to $t$:
$$ q(t) = \int_t^\infty e^{-r(s-t)}c(s)e^{-\delta(s-t)}ds $$

- $q$ price of capital goods
- $r$ discount rate
- $c$ cost of goods
- $\delta$ rate of replacement
- $t$ time of acquisition of goods
- $s$ time of supply of goods

I have the answer, but I was hoping someone would explain the intermediate points. Here, is the process similar to differentiating the functions with summation operators in discrete cases?

Comment: It's just the Leibniz rule: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Can you please include in your question an expression that exemplifies the discrete case you have in mind?

Comment: @Alecos, I mean the Riemann sum.

Comment: Can anyone walk me through the solution? Thanks!